# load custom offline maptiles only in the visible region using OSMdroid

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

The problem is when at a zoom level of 15 and above, the OSMdroid library loads complete map tiles available offline, there by making my application slow and unresponsive during panning and zoom in/out times. So, is there a way in OSMdroid where in I can access maptiles or load maptiles only in the visible portion of the screen? Or can I load maptiles onto cache, if so how? or Is this a design problem? Please ask for required code I shall post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that OSMdroid loads maptiles only in the visible portion itself and not render completly. I also understand that internally these maptiles (bitmaps) cache themselves to make render faster.